# Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : build/tmp/expandedArchives/org.jacoco.agent

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, jacoco, jacoco-plugin

Error while running test coverage using Jacoco.

I am currently using operating system Windows 10 Professional, Java 8, Gradle.

CLI to execute test coverage report I am using the command:

```
gradlew sonarqube -Dsonar.projectKey=projectKey -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.login=c231ced071c19ae0ab12342dfgd3fa17e85fd6a5
```

While I am running jacoco to publish report in local sonarqube, I am getting the following error:

> ```
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : build/tmp/expandedArchives/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.5.jar_6a2df60c47de373ea127d14406367999/jacocoagent.jar
> agent library failed to init: instrument
>
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : build/tmp/expandedArchives/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.5.jar_6a2df60c47de373ea127d14406367999/jacocoagent.jar
> agent library failed to init: instrument
>
> Process 'Gradle Test Executor 2' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>
> org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'Gradle Test Executor 2' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>           at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:417)
>   at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.DefaultWorkerProcess.onProcessStop(DefaultWorkerProcess.java:141)
> ```

Please need your input to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which gradle version are you using?

Comment: I am using gradle version 6.3.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I changed name of folders in file system to reduce the path to the project - it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Run the next command `gradlew clean build -d`, this takes a few seconds.
Then run this command `gradlew --stop`.